# Google plus => remove access to app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-oauth

I am creating an App Engine project, and I want authenticated access from Google+.

I am now getting the token from the user in this way:

```
try {
    String G_PLUS_SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    String USERINFO_SCOPE ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    String SCOPES = G_PLUS_SCOPE + " " + USERINFO_SCOPE;
    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainScreenActivity.this, mAccount.name, SCOPES);
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 3);
}
```

This works, I catch the UserRecoverableAuthException if I have no permission and ask the user with the StartActivityForResult()

But I want to test it some more, looked for a way to revoke the access, but my app is not to be found here: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

How can I revoke the access?

Comment: Is it listed here: https://plus.google.com/apps

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the correct app name in the correct Google account? It should be listed on one of the two.

Comment: It is really not there. I walked through them all...I think it is because a token has been handed out and that will expire, instead of a web application ... there has to be a difference...